# Flutter & riverpod: Using service class and refresh my view

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm trying to use riverpod with my service bluetooth class.

When I'm starting to discover all my devices, I would like to display all my devices scanned in a listview. With this code, nothing happens in my listview:

MyView.dart:

```
class ModulesDiscoverView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ModulesDiscoverView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => ref.read(bluetoothServiceProvider).discoverDevices(),
            child: const Text("Discover devices"),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: ref.watch(bluetoothServiceProvider).modulesScanned.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final module = ref.watch(bluetoothServiceProvider).modulesScanned[index];
                return Text(module.name);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Module.dart:

```
class Module {
  String name;  
  Module({required this.name});
}
```

BluetoothService.dart:

```
final bluetoothServiceProvider = Provider(BluetoothService.new);

class BluetoothService {

  final Ref ref;
  BluetoothService(this.ref);

  StreamSubscription? subscriptionDiscoverDevices;
  List<Module> modulesScanned = [];
  FlutterReactiveBle flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();


  Future<void> discoverDevices() async {
    subscriptionDiscoverDevices = flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(withServices: [SERVICE_UUID]).listen((device) {
      modulesScanned.add(Module(name: device.name));
    }, onError: (error) {});
  }
 }
```

Comment: You've effectively created a ChangeNotifierProvider and changed state without calling ref.notifyListeners().  Add that.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for your help. Is this the right way to do it? I can't really find an example for my case... I'm used to developing without riverpod... (I'm using the last version of riverpod)

Comment: Service with exposed mutate methods for their state are generally done with Notifier[Provider] or AsyncNotifier[Provider], which gives you the ability to say "state = f(state)" for your mutations.

Comment: Ok but creating a service class like this is the good practice? Or i need to move the moduleScanned list outside the class and change its type to notifier or something like that?

Comment: Generally, a Notifier or AsyncNotifier would hold a "model" object with the state. Your BluetoothService object is actually doing both the external API and the internal model management.  Splitting it up would make data and API distinctions clearer.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz do you think it's possible to write a small example with your recommandations please?

Comment: See http://riverpod.dev and Andrea Bizzotto's excellent collection of Riverpod tutorials: https://codewithandrea.com/tags/riverpod/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to how I used riverpod in my project

> chat_provider.dart

The data flow is : UI -> Provider -> Repository -> Request, after request completed, the data flow is returned in order. Your Bluetooth can also use repository to handle it.

[ChatGPT-Flutter-Web](https://github.com/MannaYang/ChatGPT-Flutter-Web/blob/main/frontend/lib/pages/chat/provider/chat_provider.dart)